# socket programming c++ connect error

Tags: c++, sockets

can you please help me on an issue of socket programming. my aim is to read a .txt file containing some ip's, open a socket and check the connection status of all the ip's.
the code that i have written for this is :-

```
int main()

{

char data[100];

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("new.txt");

myfile<<"www.google.com";

myfile<<"www.yahoo.com"

myfile.close();

ifstream readfile;

readfile.open("new.txt");

while(!readfile.eof())

{

if(!readfile.eof())

{

readfile.getline(data,100);

int status;

struct addrinfo host_info;

struct addrinfo *host_info_list;

 memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof host_info);

 host_info.ai_family = AF_INET;

 host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

 status = getaddrinfo("data", "22", &host_info, &host_info_list);

 if (status != 0)  cout << "getaddrinfo error" << gai_strerror(status) ;


else

{

 int socketfd;

socketfd = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype, 

host_info_list->ai_protocol);

if (socketfd == -1) cout << "socket error " ;

else

{

cout << "Connect()ing..."  << std::endl;

//int status;

status = connect(socketfd, host_info_list->ai_addr, host_info_list-       >  ai_addrlen);

if (status == -1)  cout << "connect error" ;

else

 {

 cout << "connection successful"<<endl;

    freeaddrinfo(host_info_list);

    close(socketfd);

}

 }}}}

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: So what is not working? Please be more specific!

Comment: when i run this code it shows getaddr error name or service not known

Comment: i dnt know whether it is being able to connect to the ips it is reading from the txt file?

Comment: Instead of doing `cout << "connect error";`  I recommend doing `cout << "connect error: " << std::strerror(errno);` to get the reason for failure printed. Also if you indent your code more people may look at it, its very hard to read flat.

Comment: galik : it shows segmentation fault.

Comment: thnx mert.your advice works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading some data from txt file into your variable `data`, but then when calling `getaddrinfo` you put a `char*` `"data"`. Use your variable:

```
status = getaddrinfo(data, "22", &host_info, &host_info_list);
```